# How to show/hide different windows using obj-c in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I' wondering how I would go about having two windows in interface builder and then being able to show and/or hide either of them from xcode with objective-c?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you've got outlets connected to each of your windows.

Then you can do `- (void)orderOut:(id)sender` to make a window invisible, or `- (void)close` if you actually want to close it.

To make the window visible and bring it to the front, do `- (void)makeKeyAndOrderFront:(id)sender`.

There's more information in the [NSWindow class reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/close).